# NetLogo: record variable for every turtle only at end of run

Tags: netlogo

I am interested to know what distance (`dist`) every of my turtles traveled over the simulation run. Following this post [How to write values in files for each turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856832/how-to-write-values-in-files-for-each-turtle), I am conscient about utilization of `file-print`.

However, this file record `dist` values per each time step over the simulation run. How can I access only the **final distance traveled by every beetle** ? Can this be included also in BehavioralSpace? Ad what is the meaning of "\r\n" ?

my code:

```
turtles-own [
  dist
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-turtles
  crt 5
  ask turtles [
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor 
  ]
end

to go
  if ticks >= 10 [stop ]
  move-turtles
  write-locations-to-file
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
    rt random 90 lt random 90
    let step.lenght random 5
    jump step.lenght
    set dist dist + step.lenght
    set label dist
  ]
end

to write-locations-to-file 
  ask turtles [ 
   file-open "/Users/.../Documents/outputs.txt"
   file-print (word who " ; " dist "\r\n" )
   file-close
  ]
end
```

and I expect final *dist* per turtle:
22
24
12
13
22

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: By 'final' distance, do you mean the distance in the last step, or do you mean the total distance over all steps?

Comment: Total distance over all steps. I thought than in BehaviorSpace uncheck Measure at each time step will help but it doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling the write-locations-to-file procedure every tick (in go) and it is doing that - writing the locations to the file. Try this instead:

```
to go
  if ticks >= 10
  [ write-locations-to-file
    stop
  ]
  move-turtles
  tick
end
```